# Sass-like functions in PostCSS

Tags: css, sass, postcss

I'm trying out PostCss and trying to find comparable features to Sass. The one feature I'm stuck on is Sass-like functions.

Here's my function is Sass:

```
// Variables.scss
$columns: 12; // Grid columns
$max-width: 1200px; // Grid max width

// Function.scss
@function grid($cols,$to-px:false) {
  @if ($to-px == false) { @return ($cols / $columns) * 100% };
  @return round(($max-width / $columns) * $cols);
}

// style.scss
.class {
  width: grid(3);
}
.class2 {
  width: grid(3,true);
}

// outputs to:

// style.css
.class {
  width: 25%;
}
.class2 {
  width: 300px;
}
```

In PostCSS can I write a function like this that returns a single CSS value?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not aware of an existing PostCSS plugin that allows you to use `@function` within CSS, but one may be out there. [`postcss-define-function`](https://github.com/titancat/postcss-define-function) provides some comparable functionalily, so maybe give that a look.

If what you need doesn't exist, it should be possible to write one, using, PostCSS's [atRule](http://api.postcss.org/AtRule.html) class (and likely some others).

However, writing a plugin like that would be pretty complicated, and is also sort of antithetical to how PostCSS encourages you to author your styles.

One of the main benefits of PostCSS is that it lets you manipulate your styles with JavaScript; rather than trying to write functions in CSS, consider writing them in JavaScript. [`postcss-functions`](https://github.com/andyjansson/postcss-functions) looks like it does just this, allowing you to expose functions—written in JavaScript—to be used within your CSS. Your given example could look something like this:

```
require('postcss-functions')({
  functions: {
    grid:(cols, totalCols, maxWidth, toPx = false) {
      return toPx
        ? `${Math.round(maxWidth / cols * totalCols)}px`
        : `${cols / totalCols * 100}%`
    }
  }
});
```

Which should allow you to write CSS like so:

#### input.css

```
.class {
  width: grid(3, 12, 1200);
}

.class2 {
  width: grid(3, 12, 1200, true);
}
```

#### output.css

```
.class {
  width: 25%;
}

.class2 {
  width: 300px;
}
```

If that doesn't work exactly as you expect it to, you can always make a pull request to the project, or write your own plugin.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

PostCSS doesn't allow you to write functions directly in CSS, however, with [extra extension](https://github.com/andyjansson/postcss-functions) you are able to write functions in pure js, which will gives you almost unlimited possibilities.

Recently there was also created an extension https://github.com/titancat/postcss-define-function which enables you to implement basic arithmetics transformations `+、-、*、/`.

In your specific case, you can also use custom measuring units. In your example you could call it `gw` and `gwpx` (grid width pixels). That would enable you to use it this way:

```
.class{
  width:3gw;
}
.class2{
  width:3gwpx;
}
```

Which will be translated to

```
.class{
  width:25%;
}
.class2{
  width:300px;
}
```

Comment: My answer is giving best solution available at this time. I am not really sure also how I would recommend two different solutions to a problem without knowing how postcss works. I stand by it, although it might be a bit outdated currently.

Comment: I would really appreciate feedback, why my answer is wrong.