# how can create inheritence in css How to DRY

Tags: css, inheritance, postcss

```css
:root {
  --c-primary: #fff;
  --c-text-color: #000000;
  --c-border-color: rgb(230, 236, 240);
  --c-gray: #6e767d;
  --c-dark-gray: #202327;

  --fade: 120ms;
}

.light.blue:root {
  --c-theme: rgb(26, 145, 218);
  --c-theme-10: rgb(26, 145, 218, 0.1);
}

.light.yellow:root {
  --c-theme: rgb(230, 156, 28);
  --c-theme-10: rgba(230, 156, 28, 0.1);
}

.light.pink:root {
  --c-theme: #e0245e;
  --c-theme-10: rgba(16, 22, 26, 0.1);
}

.light.purple:root {
  --c-theme: rgb(121, 75, 196);
  --c-theme-10: rgb(121, 75, 196, 0.1);
}

.light.orange:root {
  --c-theme: rgb(220, 84, 31);
  --c-theme-10: rgb(220, 84, 31, 0.1);
}

.light.green:root {
  --c-theme: rgb(21, 172, 89);
  --c-theme-10: rgb(21, 172, 89, 0.1);
}

/* == */

.dim.blue:root {
  --c-theme: rgb(26, 145, 218);
  --c-theme-10: rgb(26, 145, 218, 0.1);
  --c-primary: rgb(21, 32, 43);
  --c-text-color: #ffffff;
  --c-border-color: #2f3336;
  --c-gray: #6e767d;
  --c-dark-gray: #202327;
}

.dim.yellow:root {
  --c-theme: rgb(230, 156, 28);
  --c-theme-10: rgba(230, 156, 28, 0.1);
  --c-primary: rgb(21, 32, 43);
  --c-text-color: #ffffff;
  --c-border-color: #2f3336;
  --c-gray: #6e767d;
  --c-dark-gray: #202327;
}

.dim.pink:root {
  --c-theme: #e0245e;
  --c-theme-10: rgba(16, 22, 26, 0.1);
  --c-primary: rgb(21, 32, 43);
  --c-text-color: #ffffff;
  --c-border-color: #2f3336;
  --c-gray: #6e767d;
  --c-dark-gray: #202327;
}

.dim.purple:root {
  --c-theme: rgb(121, 75, 196);
  --c-theme-10: rgb(121, 75, 196, 0.1);
  --c-primary: rgb(21, 32, 43);
  --c-text-color: #ffffff;
  --c-border-color: #2f3336;
  --c-gray: #6e767d;
  --c-dark-gray: #202327;
}

.dim.orange:root {
  --c-theme: rgb(220, 84, 31);
  --c-theme-10: rgb(220, 84, 31, 0.1);
  --c-primary: rgb(21, 32, 43);
  --c-text-color: #ffffff;
  --c-border-color: #2f3336;
  --c-gray: #6e767d;
  --c-dark-gray: #202327;
}

.dim.green:root {
  --c-theme: rgb(21, 172, 89);
  --c-theme-10: rgb(21, 172, 89, 0.1);
  --c-primary: rgb(21, 32, 43);
  --c-text-color: #ffffff;
  --c-border-color: #2f3336;
  --c-gray: #6e767d;
  --c-dark-gray: #202327;
}

/* == */

.dark.blue:root {
  --c-theme: rgb(26, 145, 218);
  --c-theme-10: rgb(26, 145, 218, 0.1);
  --c-primary: #000;
  --c-text-color: #ffffff;
  --c-border-color: #2f3336;
  --c-gray: #6e767d;
  --c-dark-gray: #202327;
}

.dark.yellow:root {
  --c-theme: rgb(230, 156, 28);
  --c-theme-10: rgba(230, 156, 28, 0.1);
  --c-primary: #000;
  --c-text-color: #ffffff;
  --c-border-color: #2f3336;
  --c-gray: #6e767d;
  --c-dark-gray: #202327;
}

.dark.pink:root {
  --c-theme: #e0245e;
  --c-theme-10: rgba(16, 22, 26, 0.1);
  --c-primary: #000;
  --c-text-color: #ffffff;
  --c-border-color: #2f3336;
  --c-gray: #6e767d;
  --c-dark-gray: #202327;
}

.dark.purple:root {
  --c-theme: rgb(121, 75, 196);
  --c-theme-10: rgb(121, 75, 196, 0.1);
  --c-primary: #000;
  --c-text-color: #ffffff;
  --c-border-color: #2f3336;
  --c-gray: #6e767d;
  --c-dark-gray: #202327;
}

.dark.orange:root {
  --c-theme: rgb(220, 84, 31);
  --c-theme-10: rgb(220, 84, 31, 0.1);
  --c-primary: #000;
  --c-text-color: #ffffff;
  --c-border-color: #2f3336;
  --c-gray: #6e767d;
  --c-dark-gray: #202327;
}

.dark.green:root {
  --c-theme: rgb(21, 172, 89);
  --c-theme-10: rgb(21, 172, 89, 0.1);
  --c-primary: #000;
  --c-text-color: #ffffff;
  --c-border-color: #2f3336;
  --c-gray: #6e767d;
  --c-dark-gray: #202327;
}
```

I have a css code like that I am try to cloning tweeter clone. And in this particular part I am working on theme feature right now.

We have 3 main theme an 6 sub-theme. I am trying to combine on this lines. But I don't wanna make a code repeat. Look at my code I wanna need that logic like that but I think I can't build it. Could you please giving advice for me. And could you pls teach me about that pls

[image]

I just need this

```css
:dark {
  --c-primary: #fff;
  --c-text-color: #000000;
  --c-border-color: rgb(230, 236, 240);
  --c-gray: #6e767d;
  --c-dark-gray: #202327;

  --fade: 120ms;
}

:dim {
  --c-primary: #fff;
  --c-text-color: #000000;
  --c-border-color: rgb(230, 236, 240);
  --c-gray: #6e767d;
  --c-dark-gray: #202327;

  --fade: 120ms;
}
```

But it is not working!!

Answer (score 0):

What you normally want to have is a CSS preprocessor with functions. Something like Sass. You can define functions in Sass in order to generate your CSS code, so that you don't need to repeat yourself. I am not familiar with postcss, but there is a [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37047910/sass-like-functions-in-postcss) regarding that topic. There is also a library for [combining sass with postcss.](https://github.com/AleshaOleg/postcss-sass) That is maybe the way you want to go.

Comment: I just wanna need 
```
:dark {
  --c-primary: #fff;
  --c-text-color: #000000;
  --c-border-color: rgb(230, 236, 240);
  --c-gray: #6e767d;
  --c-dark-gray: #202327;

  --fade: 120ms;
}

:dim {
  --c-primary: #fff;
  --c-text-color: #000000;
  --c-border-color: rgb(230, 236, 240);
  --c-gray: #6e767d;
  --c-dark-gray: #202327;

  --fade: 120ms;
}

```
Like that

Comment: inheritance, functions etc. All available in Sass. See https://sass-lang.com/guide for more information.